# Devise user created with Rails generator cannot sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, credentials, salt

I'm working on a Rails Engine which will depend on Devise.

I created an installer using **Rails generator** which you can find [here](https://github.com/a-barbieri/binda/blob/master/lib/generators/binda/install/install_generator.rb#L77-L81). The installer creates the first credentials in order to access the administration panel later.

**The problem is that I cannot sign in with those credentials**. Weirdly then, if I delete the account and recreate it via Rails console, they do work. I think that's due to something happening during the installer.

Here a snippet of it:

```rb
# Binda installer generator ...

def setup_devise
  return if Rails.env.production?
  # Copy the initilializer on the application folder
  template 'config/initializers/devise.rb'
  # Add secret key
  inject_into_file 'config/initializers/devise.rb', after: "config.secret_key = '" do 
    SecureRandom.hex(64)
  end
  # Add pepper
  inject_into_file 'config/initializers/devise.rb', after: "config.pepper = '" do 
    SecureRandom.hex(64)
  end
  # some other code for mailer ...
end

def create_credentials
  @username = ask("What's your email? ['mail@domain.com']").presence || 'mail@domain.com'
  @password = ask("What's your password? ['password']").presence || 'password'
  Binda::User.create( email: @username, password: @password, password_confirmation: @password )

# Binda installer generator continue ...
```

[Here](https://github.com/a-barbieri/binda/blob/master/lib/generators/binda/install/install_generator.rb#L77-L81) the full code.

---

#### More info

I found out that even if I modify `devise.rb` file the new configuration is not loaded until the end of the installer. This means the new salt/pepper isn't considered while creating the first user. **How can I reload it** before running the `create_credentials` method?

Comment: Is the user actually being created in the db with that `Binda::User.create` call? Add a bang (eg. `create!`) to ensure that it is.

Comment: Yes the user is there... but it does not have access. If I destroy it and create it from Rails console then it does. I'll check with adding the bang.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the salt/pepper you're injecting earlier on aren't loaded when you create the user, so the password is no longer valid.

Comment: It's the same thing I have though. Or maybe running the installer doesn't consider devise config. I will try creating a second installer, which is not something I like...

Comment: I think I got the problem. After I updated `devise.rb` with new salt/pepper sequence, Devise config isn't reloaded. How can I reload it from the generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted!

The problem is that if you add salt/pepper configuration to the `devise.rb` of your application you need to reload the environment before being able to create a user with the new settings.

To do that I moved the user creation into a task. This way the installer to reload the environment (and Devise config as weel) and is able to set the encrypted password correctly.

**Installer**

```
# lib/generators/myEngine/install/install_generator.rb
def create_credentials
  rake 'binda_create_initial_user'
end
```

**Task**

```
# lib/tasks/binda.rake
desc "Create initial user"
task :binda_create_initial_user => :environment do
  username = 'mail@domain.com'
  password = 'password'
  Binda::User.create!( email: username, password: password, password_confirmation: password )
end
```

If you want to keep asking for mail and password:

```rb
# lib/tasks/binda.rake
desc "Create first user"
task :binda_create_initial_user => :environment do
    STDOUT.puts "What is your email? [mail@domain.com]"
  username = STDIN.gets.strip
  username = 'mail@domain.com' if username.blank?
    STDOUT.puts "What is your password? [password]"
  password = STDIN.gets.strip
  password = 'password' if password.blank?
  Binda::User.create!( email: username, password: password, password_confirmation: password )
end
```